# WifiManager returns BSSID 00:00:00:00:00:00

Tags: android, wifimanager

I use the following code to get BSSID:

```
public static String getBSSID(Context context) {
    WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    return wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo().getBSSID();
}
```

When i use this code when the device doesn't have sim card it works fine.
But when i have a sim card, even when i am using wifi - me returned value is 00:00:00:00:00:00.
Anybody knows why it happens?

Comment: When you are "using wifi" are you actually connected to an AP, or is Wifi just turned on?

Comment: Does the `WifiInfo` object provide any other valid data?

Comment: well it does. But now i also get my bssid right...
I have no idea why it dodn't work all day on 2 different devices, but maybe i just had problems with my wifi and i didn't notice..
thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had same problem myself.  most of the chances is that you are not checking if you are currently connected to the WiFi before attempting to get the bssid:

```
public static boolean isConnectedToRouter(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager onnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo wifi = onnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    if (wifi.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

only if this method returns true, then you can obtain bssid.   attemping to get BSSID when you are not connected to specific Wifi will return 00:00:00:00:00:00